# css3 animation and discrepancy between style and computed style

Tags: css, animation

I am getting into css3 animations and I stumbled upon the animation-fill-mode property which
basically can apply the values of the animation to the element, after the animation has ended.

By default, when an animation ends, the element is restored to its original state.

So for example

```
 #box{
     width: 100px;
     position: absolute;
 }

#box.startAnimation{

    animation-name:first, second;
    animation-duration:5s, 5s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-delay:0s, 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@-moz-keyframes first
{
    0%   {left:40%; top:0px;background:cyan}
    100% {left:100px; top:0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes second
{
     0%   {left:100px; top:0px;}
     100% {left:0px; top:300px;width:300px}
}
```

The forwards animation-fill-mode will make the element on which the startAnimation class is applied, to be 300px width and positioned 300px top and 0px left.

However, these values are applied to the element's computed style and not the css style.

This can lead to inconsistencies because if someone now tries to get i.e, the element's width, he would get back 100px and not 300px.

The above can really get weird in large projects, where the animations are made and there is javascript logic which needs to access properties as width, height, left etc.

I mean there is this discrepancy between computed style and the one you read via div.style.width (for example)

I am curious to hear opinions or solutions to the above problem

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think it would depend on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you have a more specific use case of a problem you are trying to solve, then I might be able to get more specific on an answer.

In the case you have above i wouldn't use keyframes. In most projects I find that i don't need keyframes unless I am making some kind of advanced animation like a man walking or something. For most web interfaces a transition and a class change seems to work fine.

I would have a base class and a transition class and use javascript to add the transition class. Then the state would remain and be consistent because it's coming from the class you added and not from an end of a keyframe.

```
.base-class { width: 100px; left: 0; top: 0; -webkit-transition: 1s all; }
.transition-class { width: 300px; -webkit-transform: translateX(300px); }

$('.base-class').on('click', function(){ $(this).addClass('transition-class'); });
```

You can also use JS to find the end of the animation if necessary

```
$('.base-class').on('-webkit-transition-end', function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    alert(width);
})
```

(also i would use translateX instead of left. it's a bit faster)